# Replacing a string with newline character with another string

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I have a huge file containing datasets such as:

```
100  S|||
100  S|d1|||88|||
100  S|0d|f6||f630|589f||
```

I need to replace `|||` with `|||||||`, only if the line contains no more pipes other than a single `|||` sequence.

I tried using sed command for this requirement:

```
sed -i 's/|||/|||||||/g' input.txt
```

However, it is changing records in second line as well, which is not intended.

What would be the correct command usage? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command with capture groups to match non-pi[e characters before and after `|||`:

```sh
sed -E 's/^([^|]*)(\|\|\|)([^|]*)$/\1\2||||\3/' file

100  S|||||||
100  S|d1|||88|||
100  S|0d|f6||f630|589f||
```

**Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `([^|]*)`: Match 0 or more non-pipe characters in capture group #1
- `(\|\|\|)`: Match 3 pipe characters in capture group #2
- `([^|]*)`: Match 0 or more non-pipe characters in capture group #3
- `$`: End
- `\1\2||||\3` is replacement pattern that inserts `||||` after back-reference #2 i.e. `\2` while putting back `\1` and `\3` as is.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`, you could try following. Written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk 'gsub(/\|/,"&")==3{gsub(/\|\|\|/,"&||||")} 1' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                       ##Starting awk program from here.
gsub(/\|/,"&")==3{          ##checking if line has only 3 ||| then do following.
  gsub(/\|\|\|/,"&||||")    ##Globally substituting ||| with itself and |||| here.
}
1                           ##printing current line here.
' Input_file                ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^[^|]*|||[^|]*$/s/|||/&&|/' file
```

If a line only contains 3 consecutive `|`'s, replace them by 7 `|`'s.